# Webpack can't read from outside the root directory

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I get this error when I try to import a file outside webpack root directory

```
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" 
specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "d:\\xprojects"
```

I have something like this

```
xprojects
├── shared
    ├── index.js
├── project
    ├── main.js
    └── webpack.config.js
```

in `main.js` I'm trying to `import Shared from '../shared/index'`

I tried to include this shared directory in all my loaders but still no luck

```
include: [
   path.resolve(__dirname, "./"),
   path.resolve(__dirname, "./../shared")
 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the plugin "transform-runtime"

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **cmd** as administrator Mode.

It's worked for me

Enjoy!